# How to calculate eingenvalues for each matrix in a 4D tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, eigenvalue, tensor

I have a 4D tensor at size of [batch_size, channels, height, width]([16, 64, 24, 24]), but I need to calculate the eigenvalue for each 24x24 matrix to obtain a 2D tensor at size of [batch_size, channels]([16, 64]) in which each element represents the eigenvalue of corresponding matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function to do that directly. But, you can loop over the input tensor to construct the required eigen tensor and then reshape it.

```
# Supposing your tensor is a
out = []
for bs in range(a.size(0)):
    for c in range(a.size(1)):
        e, _ = torch.eig(a[bs, c, :, :])
        out.append(torch.max(e))
out = torch.stack(out).view(a.size(0), a.size(1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution!